# Execute current line in Bash from Vim

Tags: bash, vim

This question is similar to *[Vim: execute current file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449591/vim-execute-current-file)*, but instead of executing the current file I want to execute only the current line.

Is this possible?

Ideally, I am looking for solutions which can have side effects in the outer shell.

For example, suppose I have the following line:

```
alias foo=bar
```

After running the command in Vim, if I start a shell with `:sh`, the alias `foo` is available, but if I quit `vim` using `:q`, then the alias is no longer available.

Comment: Maybe someone thinks it belongs to superuser.

Comment: That should be request to move, not a downvote? Or am I misunderstanding stackoverflow rules? I put the question on SO because SO has a `vim` tag.

Comment: This question is fine here, in my view it fits in "software tools commonly used by programmers". Vim and bash are exactly that... I don't think the downvotes are justified.

Comment: There is no way to change the environment of a parent process. Sorry. (And I don't know how you can change the environment of future shells, either.)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Sure thing, you can 'write' any content of the current file into the [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) of another program:

```
:.w !bash
```

Here `.` (the part before *w*) refers to the range of lines you are writing, and `.` is only the current line. Then you use `!bash` to write those lines to Bash.

Comment: This is great, but the output isn't persistent in the way that `:!bash [my commands]` would be (i.e. I can later issue `:!` and see the output again). Is there a way to adapt this to put the output in _that_ buffer (whatever it is)?

Comment: @AlecJacobson You could try this: `yy` to yank the current line, then `:!<Control-r>"` to paste the contents of the current line into the Vim command-line.

Comment: nice, that works great for single lines. Your answer above works for entire selections, is there are a a <CTRL-R> trick for that? If I try yanking multiple lines I end up with a lot of `^M`s in a single command rather than multiple commands.

Comment: I bound this command to `,r` in `~/.vimrc` with the following: `nnoremap ,r :.w !bash<CR>`. Now in command mode, to execute a line, move the cursor to that line and type `,r`. The output will be displayed right in the editor.

Comment: @DaanBakker, I would stress in the answer that the space is before, and not after, the question mark, because as you know it makes a lot of difference, and can be useful for one of the most useful tricks ever: the [write with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078429/5825294) trick.

Comment: Run  `.w !sudo bash` to execute the current line as root.

Comment: Wow! So simple and the only appropriate answer to this question. And still there have been answers that end in unwanted results. 6 years later.

Answer (score 44):

I do this sort of thing all the time with:

```
:exec '!'.getline('.')
```

You can even create a mapping in your .vimrc:

```
nmap <F6> :exec '!'.getline('.')
```

Comment: I like this answer. You can also do `@"` instead of `.getline('.')` to execute yanked text instead of one line.

Answer (score 24):

Move the cursor to that line, and in normal mode press:

```
!!bash<cr>
```

Comment: This has the unfortunate effect of replacing the current line with the output, which is not desired.

Comment: @merlin2011 if the external (bash) command has output, you don't want to display it in buffer? or you want it below the "current line"?

Comment: Below or suppressed are both okay. I am executing the command for its side effect rather than to get its output in this case.

Answer (score 10):

This could be a comment if I can comment.

Concerning redirect/pipe lines of current buffer in Vim to external command, inspired by Daan Bakker's great answer, I wrote I answer here
(*[Save and run at the same time in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601039/vim-save-and-run-at-the-same-time/40002312#40002312)*), on an question concerning
running a Python script (current buffer).

Beside running the whole buffer, how to run a range of line via an external command is demonstrated.

To save time, I just copy it below.

```
#####################
```

In Vim, you could simply redirect any range of your current buffer to an external command (be it 'bash', 'python', or you own Python script).

```
# Redirect the whole buffer to 'python'
:%w !python
```

Suppose your current buffer contains the two lines as below,

```
import numpy as np
print np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
```

then `:%w !python` will run it, be it saved or not. And print something like below on your terminal,

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Of course, you could make something persistent, for example, some keymaps.

```
nnoremap <F8> :.w !python<CR>
vnoremap <F8> :w !python<CR>
```

The first one runs the current line. The second one runs the visual selection, via the Python interpreter.

```
#!! Be careful, in Vim ':w!python' and ':.w !python' are very different, the
first writes (creates or overwrites) a file named 'python' with thew contents of
the current buffer. The second redirects the selected cmdline range (here dot .,
which mean current line) to an external command (here 'python').
```

For cmdline range, see

```
:h cmdline-ranges
```

Not the below one, which concerning normal command, not cmdline one.

```
:h command-range
```

This was inspired by *[Execute current line in Bash from Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883917/execute-current-line-in-bash-from-vim/19883963#19883963)*.

Answer (score 5):

Add this mapping to your .vimrc file,

```
nmap <leader>E yyp:.!csh<CR>
```

Explanation:

1. `yy`
   Yank current line
2. `p`
   Paste yanked line below (and the cursor goes to this next row)
3. `:.!csh<CR>`
   Execute (using `csh`) this newly pasted line in place. The output of this line replaces this current line, thus before executing the line was yanked and pasted below.

Answer (score 1):

If I have a command on a line of text within vi/Vim like this"

ls -la

Position the cursor anywhere on the line and do
":.!!" and press return.

That is: *colon dot bang bang return*

That will execute the text in that line in the current shell from within vi/Vim and have the output inserted within the text file.

I'm thinking that is what you were asking? It's like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following command run on terminal,

```
seq 0 10 | xargs printf "%02x "
```

Expected output is,

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a
```

Consider you have this above command written in a file. To execute this command get this respective output back in that file, you can add this mapping in yours .vimrc,

```
nmap <leader>E :exec 'r!'.getline('.')<CR>
```

Note that, to execute above mentioned line, you need to write it with adding escape char for '`%`' as follows,

```
seq 0 10 | xargs printf "\%02x "
```

Go this line in your file and press `<leader>E`. In my case, `<leader>` is mapped to `,` hence I will press `,E`